# Populating ListView throws android.R.id.list

Tags: android, json, android-listview, populate

I'm getting data from my server through JSON, I'm trying to display that data I'm getting in a ListView, but everytime I'm getting this error `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'.` Everything I'm getting from the server is good, data setting is good, but just adding it to a listView isn't working. I don't know why. Am I doing something wrong in here?

**Code Where I populate ListView**

```
public class List extends ListActivity {

    String myLat = "";
    String myLng = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout._list);
        getLocations();
        new GetTask().execute(myLat, myLng);
    }

    private void getLocations() {
        String[] locations = getApplicationContext().fileList();
        FileInputStream fis;

        for (int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            if (locations[i].equals("my_latitude")) {
                try {
                    fis = openFileInput(locations[i]);
                    byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
                    while (fis.read(input) != -1) {
                        myLat += new String(input);
                    }
                    fis.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (locations[i].equals("my_longitude")) {
                try {
                    fis = openFileInput(locations[i]);
                    byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
                    while (fis.read(input) != -1) {
                        myLng += new String(input);
                    }
                    fis.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void CreateList(Objecter[] objecter) {

         this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         R.layout.my_row));
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> List = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < objecter.length; i++) {

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("Name", objecter[i].getName());
            map.put("Latitude", Float.toString(objecter[i].getLatitude()));
            map.put("Longitude", Float.toString(objecter[i].getLongitude()));
            map.put("Distance", Double.toString(Math.round(objecter[i]
                    .getDistance() * 1000) / 1000.0));

            List.add(map);
        }

        final ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list);
        //final ListView list = getListView();
        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, List);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                TextView txtLat = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(
                        position - list.getFirstVisiblePosition())
                        .findViewById(R.id.lblListlatitude);
                TextView txtLng = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(
                        position - list.getFirstVisiblePosition())
                        .findViewById(R.id.lblListlongitude);
                String lat = txtLat.getText().toString();
                String lng = txtLng.getText().toString();
                Log.v("Lat ", "Lat of selected item is " + lat);
                Log.v("Lng ", "Lng of selected itemis " + lng);

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?&saddr="
                        + myLat + "," + myLng + "&daddr=" + lat + "," + lng);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            };
        });
    }

    class GetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... data) {
            String lat = data[0];
            String lng = data[1];

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONArray json = jParser
                    .getJSONFromUrl("http://www.mysite.eu/index.php/searchJSON?lat="
                            + lat + "&lng=" + lng + "&radius=10");

            return json;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {

            if (result != null) {

                try {
                    Log.v(result.getString(0), result.getString(0));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

//              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done",
//                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
//              toast.show();
//              Log.d("whut", "" + result.length());

                String[] building = new String[result.length()];
                Objecter[] objecter= new Objecter[result.length()];
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject row;
                        row = result.getJSONObject(i);
                        building[i] = row.getString("Name");
                        building[i] += "" + row.getDouble("Latitude");
                        building[i] += "" + row.getDouble("Longitude");
                        building[i] += ". Distance: "
                                + row.getDouble("distance") + "km";

                        String Name = row.getString("Name");
                        float lat = (float) row.getDouble("Latitude");
                        float lng = (float) row.getDouble("Longitude");
                        float dist = (float) row.getDouble("distance");

                        objecter[i] = new Objecter(Name, lat, lng, dist);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.v("Noooooooooooo", "You were the chosen one");
                    Log.e("Noooooooooooo", "Dis iz die erreur: " + e.toString());
                }

                CreateList(objecter);
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enable internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eu.example.www/eu.example.www.List}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:311)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at eu.example.wwwList.onCreate(List.java:37)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
06-09 14:54:13.970: E/AndroidRuntime(17826):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `_list.xml` must contain a `ListView` with the id `"@android:id/list"`

Like so:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) on `ListActivity`

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

Comment: But I have a `Listview` in `my_list.xml` with `id my_list`. That is why I set in my code the following line ` final ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list);`

Comment: If you are extending ListActivity you cannot set your own id. It *MUST* be as I describe above.

Comment: You can get your ListView object by calling `getListView()` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView())

Comment: Where exactly should I call `getListView()`

Comment: `final ListView list = getListView();` And of course change the id in XML as described above.

Comment: Ok, but like this I'm only getting a page with a `ListView`, and not with my other components. I've also got a few `Checkboxes` on my page.

Comment: I can't really help without seeing your XML. Anyway I think I have answered your question above :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31484/discussion-between-mxx-and-ken-wolf)